# Why do I break same-origin policy when loading javascript-files with wordpress?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, same-origin-policy

searching through all the forum's topics I couldn't find the solution concerning my issue. I attempt to include my javascript-files by the wordpress-function wp_enqueue_script(), i.e.

```
wp_enqueue_script(
    'c-studio',
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/cStudio.js',
    array( 'jquery' ),
    '1.2', true
);
```

However, all the browsers except firefox(due to different security settings?) throw an error message like "Access to restricted URI denied". This notice comes up when I select the Firebug addon and open the script-tab.

Yes, that has something to do with same-origin policy, cross domain queries are - in most cases - not permitted etc. etc. But the thing is, that I just want to **load my script files locally**, that is I do not proceed a cross-domain request neither I call the files from different domains... I just call the scripts by wordpress' functions.php.

So, does somebody have a solution on how to circumvent this same-origin policy issue? To exemplify my problem you can visit the following web-page: http://www.studio-change.de However, the site, that I develope for my clients, is still under construction due to the specified problem...

Thank you very much!

Comment: "throw an error massage like " — What is the exact error message? (I don't get an error message like that when I visit that URL in Chrome, but see   [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it))

Comment: Is it possible that the local version of your site that you are testing on, is getting the external template directory url? Check the values of "home", and "siteurl" in the "wp_options" table in your local installation, and make sure they point to the right place.

Comment: @Quentin Firebug still prompts "Access to restricted URI denied" (Opera, Chrome, Safari, IE are not loading the scripts - this is really odd). Even some stylesheets are not being loaded due to same-origin policy. I am sorry that I cannot narrow my problem, as the scripts are still not loaded for debugging them.

Yes, these options are pointing to the correct place, in other words I do not load the stylesheets and scripts by an external file.